# Protractor find an element by tag inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, protractor

I've got a div in an HTML Page of which the name is always known and inside this div there is an href, the details of which are not known.  It could be the direct child of the parent or it could be a further grandchild.   Looks something like this:

```
<div class="divName">
    ...
        <a href="some url">some text</a>
    ...
</div>
```

I know that there will only be one link within this div, so I want to find the one link and click it.

I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
    element(by.classname('divName')).find('a').click();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is exactly. Is this link dynamically created or is it hard coded?

Comment: dynamically created would be a good way of looking at it.  basically I never know what is going to be in the link except that it is an <a href> so I would like to navigate to the div and then to the only link in the div and I'm having trouble figuring out the syntax for that.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
element(by.css('.divName a')).click();
```

Or the shorter notation:

```
$('.divName a').click();
```

Comment: or `element(by.css('.classA, .classB, .classC a')).click();` for more classes

Answer (score 1):

figured out a solution:

```
ptor.findElement(protractor.By.className('clsName'))
    .findElements(protractor.By.tagName('a'))
    .then(function(links){
        links[0].click();
        //place expects here, otherwise it will run async and your expects will be hit 
        //before the lookup
});
```

This seems to work pretty well for my purposes

Answer (score 0):

One line answer

try with `element('.divName a').click();`

Comment: You need to pass a locator to the element finder: `element(by.xxx())`

Answer (score -2):

it seems sytax error in your code

use this

```
element(by.className('divName')).find('a').click();
```