# Select a dynamic number inside a span

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, selenium, protractor

I'm using an automation framework with selenium and protractor, coding in JavaScript. However, this part of the app is made without Angular. I have a quantity field with a plus and minus button to increase the number. I need to select the number itself for my test.

Here's the DOM with a '2' as the number

```
<div class="modify-product padding-lg-top hide-on-review">
 <b data-lang-key="store.qty">Qty:</b>
 <span class="modify-action">
  <span class="remove">-</span>
  <span class="product-quantity">2</span>
  <span class="add">+</span>
 </span>
</div>
```

If I use JQuery in the console, I can select the 2 with the following:

```
$('.cart-product .product-quantity').text()
```

Now in selenium, I'm trying to use the following selector:

```
return element(by.css('.cart-product .product-quantity').text())
```

This has so far proved unsuccessful. I've also tried .val() and a few other methods, but everything I try returns the entire span element or comes back as undefined.

Thoughts?

Comment: I still get the error     TypeError: element(...).text is not a function

Comment: Its not`text`. You need to use `getText ()`.

Comment: Whatever the method for get text would be, should't be called on element object? and not inside as currently used. Find the element then get the text like element(by.css('css_selector')).getText()

Answer (score 0):

See following links.

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35191666/how-to-locate-dynamic-elements-in-protractor)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21536179/protractor-find-an-element-by-tag-inside-a-div)

Important - Never use xpath for this kind of scenarios

Answer (score 0):

```
return element(by.className('product-quantity')).getText();
```

Remember getText() returns a promise.So you have to use then() to get the value

Answer (score 0):

Remember that protractor methods return promises always because they are async operations. Your test should be as the following:

```
let quantities = element.all(by.css('.product-quantity'));
quantities.get(0).then(function(el) {
  expect(el.getText()).to.become('2');
});
```